# Access control in Google Cloud SQL: Authorized apps

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have been using an instance of google Cloud SQL with several App Engine Applications for a while, and today I noticed the following announcement "You have not authorized any App Engine Applications and you do not have an IP Address assigned to your Cloud SQL instance.  You will no be able to connect to your database in any way." But that's no true, actually it's running properly with the apps. Anyone has the same announcement in the Access Control or Google is having an issue? Or I should change the settings?

Comment: I see this and I infact cannot connect my cloud SQL to any app. You are saying this isn't causing you any real error?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and we're currently working on a fix.